# Pass newly created object to multiple storyboards

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have the following setup.

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath 
            Duration="0:0:2" 
            Source="X" 
            Completed="Timeline_OnCompleted"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M42.473003,3.8059855 L281.428,3.8059855"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M42.473003,3.8059855 L281.428,3.8059855"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:2" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)" >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M286.789,2.116 L420.289,-184.884 L306.789,-240.384"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M286.789,2.116 L420.289,-184.884 L306.789,-240.384"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Animation_Path" Canvas.Left="3.409" Canvas.Top="53.412" Margin="155.184,649.19,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>


    <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="588,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_5"/>


</Grid>
```

And code behind it.

```
        private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectToMove move = new ObjectToMove();
        Animation_Path.Children.Add(move);

        var sb1 = FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
        sb1.Begin(move);
    }
```

I got this working. But how is possible to pass the newly created object to the second `storyboard2` after the first one is finished..? I prefer doing this in code if possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, why we can not put all animations in one storyboard and just set tweak the timeline, what's your intent?

Comment: @Edgars This because in my project I have different segments (shapes) and each of those must be controllable on it own. I have tried to put all of it in 1 animation. It works fine. But the product owner asks for what I am asking now. My Intent to have a start storyboard -  which is sb1 in this case - create new object and as soon as sb1 is finished pass the newly created object to sb2. Hopefully this clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you could use `Completed` event for this. Let's try this, with multiple storyboards sequence.

PS. Any comments about converting event handler to await format are welcome.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var move1 = new ObjectToMove();
    Animation_Path.Children.Add(move1);

    var storyBoardsToRun = new[] {"Storyboard1", "Storyboard2"};

    storyBoardsToRun 
        .Select(sbName => FindResource(sbName) as Storyboard)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(async sb => await sb.BeginAsync(move1));
}

public static class StoryBoardExtensions
{
    public static Task BeginAsync(this Storyboard sb, FrameworkContentElement element)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        sb.Completed += delegate
        {
            source.SetResult(null);
        };
        sb.Begin(element);
        return source.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new object in sb1.completed ..? We have already created a new object just above. THAT object must be passed to the second SB. I have tested your suggestion, but nothing happens. sb2 is not getting triggered, even doing so sb2.begin(move1)

Comment: From your comment above : "create new object and as soon as sb1 is finished pass the newly created object to sb2".

Comment: I gave it another try, it works. But what if I have 5 storyboards and willing to pass the object to each storyboard. Like a chain. Doing this might not be a proper way to go about it. \

Comment: `.ForEach(async sb => await sb.BeginAsync(move1));`is showing error => doesn't exisit. And by `timeline`I assume you mean `sb` .?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114126/discussion-between-edgars-and-user3641381).